# Response UDP packets not arriving regardless of right ip and port after sending via specific interface

Tags: c++, sockets, routes, udp, wireshark

I have set up a few routing rules to make sure that a packet is sent over the same interface as the socket is bound to. (The sendto function in C++ will try to choose the best possible interface based on the destination address). I am sending UDP packets to other devices both in and out of my local network, and in return they respond by sending UDP packets to the same address. Using **Wireshark** I can verify that this happens.

But although the packets arrive at the network stack, and can thus be read by Wireshark, they are not received by the socket bound to the specific interface.

The routing rules on my Ubuntu system are the following:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -t mangle -p udp -s 193.156.108.78 --sport 12346 -j MARK --set-mark 21
ip rule add fwmark 21 table 21
ip route add dev wlan0 default via 193.156.108.1 table 21
```

I presume that I need to make changes to my **iptables** for incoming traffic, but I am unsure what is not working, since the the addresses on both the ethernet frame and the ip header seem to be correct.

**EDIT:**

Using the LOG target in iptables I have determined that the packets use the **PREROUTING** in the **mangle** table, but not the **PREROUTING** in the **nat** table. Neither does it go through the **INPUT** tables. I do not know why at this point.

The iptables **TRACE** that is set as a rule in **PREROUTING** in **raw** traces the packet. It goes through the rules in **PREROUTING mangle** (Nothing I tried yet got me anywhere) and eventually stops there with some **policy #**. The number stands for which rule in that specific table is chosen. The default policy, which is **ACCEPT** everywhere, is the highest number available. (The number of user rules + 1)

Using `iptables -L -nvx` and `iptables -S -v` the number of accepted packets and the rules can be visualized.

So even though my packet seems to be accepted, still it is dropped somewhere. I could really use some help here.

This is a full trace of one such packet:

```
Nov  1 09:18:23 XXX kernel: [ 2377.505697] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:3 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=193.156.108.67 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=6428 DPT=12346 LEN=63
Nov  1 09:18:23 XXX kernel: [ 2377.505721] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=193.156.108.67 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=6428 DPT=12346 LEN=63
```

**EDIT2:**

UDP packets send back from a device within in the same wireless network does work. Also it works for a socket bound to eth0 for both local and external networks. These routes normally skip the **nat PREROUTING** part as well, and go straight to the ip routing table. ([Visualization](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Diagrama_linux_netfilter_iptables.gif)) Which is where something goes wrong apparently. I have not been able to verify that redirections to another table actually work (either using **MARK** or `ip rule add from "source" table #`), suggestions about this are welcome as well. Also I have not been able to figure out what should be in the routing table to allow the packet to continue to **INPUT**.

**UNSATISFACTORY SOLUTION:**

Setting the **log_martians** variable in **/etc/sysctl.conf** I can finally see that the packet is dropped, due to reverse path filtering presumably. Fortunately setting the **rp_filter** variables to **2** in the same file solves the problem.

As explained [here](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering) packets will be blocked, if the interface on which they come in can not find a route to the source. Setting this **rp_filter** value to 2 will solve my problem because it relies on the fact that my default interface can in fact route to this source.

**REMAINING QUESTIONS:**

For some reason setting this **rp_filter** value to 0 does not always work (It should drop no martian packets at all). Don't know why that is.

Furthermore I do not really like this solution and would gladly implement a better one if available. It seems to me that I need to find a way to give the wlan0 interface a standard way to route to this source, not just by marking packets. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this problem is setting the **rp_filter** value in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to `2`. You can do this for each interface separately or set them both for default and all. I am not entirely sure how these values work, but I think that default sets each new interface to that specific value, and all sets all current interfaces to that value (But there might be exceptions to that?).

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
```

Note that you have to reset sysctl and the network manager to make sure that the new settings are used.

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
service network-manager restart
```

**EDIT:**

A better way would be to change your routing calls to:

```
ip rule add from 193.156.108.78 table 21
ip route add dev wlan0 default via 193.156.108.1 table 21
```

This way your system will be able to find a routing path to the source address, which will let the package through without setting the **rp_filter**.